# Why do I see different versions when I run `ssh -V` compared with `sshd -V`

Tags: openssh

To update OpenSSH in Ubuntu 18 LTS to version 8, I followed these steps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598842/392505

I now see the desired version when I run `ssh -V`

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

But if I run `sshd -V` I see the old version:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

Do I need to take some additional actions so I see the proper version when I check the version with sshd?

Comment: Most users who seek to "upgrade" like that are worried about vulnerabilities and published CVEs. However, it's unnecessary: The Ubuntu Security Team patches CVEs *without* bumping to a higher version. You *can* manually upgrade components -- it's YOUR system. The point is merely that you don't NEED to in order to be safe and secure.

Comment: Also, if you install from source, you have to keep an eye on bug fixes.  But if you stay with the version that comes with your version of Ubuntu (as long as it's still supported), then you'll get these patches just by doing a periodic system upgrade.

Comment: What is your `PATH`? by default, the `./configure` script uses `PREFIX=/usr/local` so whether you find the old or new version of the ssh client depends on the order of `/usr/local/bin` versus `/usr/bin`, whereas for sshd it will depend on the order of `/usr/local/sbin` versus `/usr/sbin`. Also make sure the "old" value is not hashed by your shell (ex. bash `hash -r`).

Comment: ... also note that if you have installed sshd in /usr/local/sbin then it may not affect your ssh *service* since the service file is likely hard-wired to use /usr/sbin/sshd

Comment: 'Most users who seek to "upgrade" like that'.  Is there a non-manual way to upgrade OpenSSH to version 8 on Ubuntu 18?